# Переход с древнего Exchange 5.5 на линуховый почтовик

Tags: linux, email, exchange

Вообщем, есть потребность перевести всех пользователей (10к-11к голов) с этого древнего почтовика на линуксовый аналог (смотрю в сторону решения iRedMail). Но всех разом перевести не смогу, так как филиалы разбросаны по всей стране, а нужно, чтоб почтовик работал без перебоя.

Есть один центральный сервер Exchange 5.5 и региональные дочерние, которые всю почту пересылают через центральный. На серверах письма не хранятся долго. Все письма сохраняются у самого пользователя в Outlook. Так вот, хочу поставить iRedMail и постепенно перевести всех пользователей туда.

Так вот, как сделать, чтоб почтовики нормально "общались", чтоб почта бегала?Почтовый домен и адреса ящиков не должны меняться - приказ руководства. 
Может можно как-то дублировать письма, чтоб и в эксченж, и айредмейл уходили? Или возможно ли временно поднять "промежуточный" сервак? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Или может в последующих Exchange есть какие-то специальные средства для синхронизации с другими почтовиками? Просто как вариант - мигрировать эксченж на новые версии, а потом уже заняться переводом.

Comment: Сервера по одинаковым протокола работают, заменил один на другой и разницы нет.

Comment: Вот так просто заменить не получится потому, что нужно установить клиентскую часть на компы пользователей, кроме этого еще и провести инструктаж этих пользователей.  Все 10 тыс голов одновременно - нереально. Поэтому нужно постепенно

Comment: Тебя уволят. ;) Поставь второй сервер в параллель, если получится такое сделать.

Comment: Думаю надо начать тренироваться на кошках, т.е. добавить в сеть еще один старый ексчендж, завести пару пользователей настроенных на него. не подключая клиентов послать им пару писем, что бы осели в эксчендже, ожидая, что их заберут. Поднять линуксовый сервер для замены данного, убедится, что вы знаете как перенести ожидающие письма с эксченджа на него. собственно перенести письма, поднять сервер на том же адресе, что был у эксченджа, убедится что сервер работает с остальной сетью. Проверить что тестовые клиенты без изменения настроек подключились новому серверу и получили ожидающую почту